# How do I scanf the last two digits in C?

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to figure out if there is a simpler way in C to `scanf()` a certain part of an inputted number by the user.

#### Following the code:

```
printf("Enter opcode:\n");
scanf("%1d", &opcode);
```

If an user inputs the number 240, `scanf("%1d", &opcode);` will save the first digit only in `opcode`

Is there a way to select only the last two digits?

Comment: To read only the last two digits needs the _mind reader_ specifier which is not available in C11.  Just read the entire input and do the math.

Comment: read the input as a string and then once you have that isolate the last two digits of the input if it is numeric.

Comment: Do `scanf("%d",&opcode); opcode %= 100;`

Comment: what do you mean by "do the math"?

Comment: See [@Craig Estey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53356545/how-do-i-scanf-the-last-two-digits-in-c#comment93590716_53356545).

Comment: He means what @CraigEstey said in his comment just above yours.

Comment: Mister Tusk  Are you concerned about input values that might be **huge** (hundreds of digits) or are they within the `long long` range? +/- 9,000,000,000,000,000,000 ish?  I would not expect opcodes to be so big.

Comment: @chux my input values range between 001 and 899. I am building a CARDIAC computer simulator.

Comment: Are the _always_ 3 digits like with leading zeros in `001` when less than 100?

Comment: @CraigEstey that doesn't give me the last two digits, only the first one.

Comment: @chux yes. If they start with a `0` that means a certain operation will be performed.

Comment: Mister Tusk, did you still use `scanf("%1d", &opcode);` with `@Craig Estey` idea or change to `scanf("%d",&opcode);`?

Comment: I have just update my code. It works now! @CraigEstey

Comment: If alway 3 digits, then `scanf("%*1c%d", &opcode);`.  It depends on the level of error checking wanted.  Considering CARDIAC, I'd want lots of error checking.  Code should not use `scanf()` at all, but `fgets()`.  Good luck.

Comment: `scanf()` (mostly) does things sequentially, and doesn't have a means of anticipating which digits are last until it finds what comes after - at which point, it won't go back and rescan to get the bits you want.   Try either reading an `int` as usual, then use basic math to extract the last two digits, or read all input as a string (e.g. using `fgets()`) and interpret the string to work out what is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to handle the task is to read the input as a string. Then perform validations, e.g. number of characters entered, that last two characters are valid hex-digits, etc.. and then use your conversion of choice to convert the last two digits to an unsigned value.

When taking input, it is recommended that you use a *line-oriented* function to read the entire line and then parse what you need from the line. The benefits are three-fold (1) you get an independent validation of the read; (2) you get an independent validation of the conversion; and (3) what remains in the input buffer doesn't depend on the `scanf` *conversion specifier* used.

A short example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXC 1024   /* if you need a constant #define one (or more) */

int main (void) {

    char buf[MAXC];     /* buffer to hold line (don't skimp on size) */

    printf ("Enter opcode: ");          /* prompt */
    if (fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {     /* read entire line */
        char *p;            /* pointer - to set to last 2 digits */
        size_t len;         /* length of the string entered */
        buf[(len = strcspn (buf, "\r\n"))] = 0; /* get length/trim '\n' */
        if (len < 2) {      /* validate at least 2 characters entered */
            fputs ("error: minimum 2-characters required.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        p = buf + len - 2;  /* set p to point to next to last char */
        if (!isxdigit(*p) || !isxdigit(*(p+1))) {   /* validate hex digits */
            fputs ("error: last 2 chars are not hex-digits.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        printf ("last 2 digits: %s\n", p);  /* output last 2 digits */
        /* perform conversion of choice here 
        * (suggest strtoul or sscanf) 
        */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** choosing the conversion is left to you. Also note how you handle the `'\n'` included in the buffer by `fgets` is also up to you. Above it is simply overwritten with the *nul-terminating* character)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/opcodelast2
Enter opcode: 240
last 2 digits: 40
```

Other results:

```
Enter opcode: 40
last 2 digits: 40

Enter opcode: 3240
last 2 digits: 40

Enter opcode: 324a
last 2 digits: 4a

Enter opcode: 4g
error: last 2 chars are not hex-digits.

Enter opcode: 4
error: minimum 2-characters required.
```

You can adjust the tests (e.g. `isdigit` or `isxdigit`) to meet your particular needs. You can (and should) include a test that `len < MAXC - 1` to ensure the entire line was read and that additional characters do not remain unread (e.g. a cat went to sleep on the keyboard). Let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score -2):

The code of @Craig Estey can be broken if you enter a big number.

```
int main()
{
    char str[100];
    do {
        scanf("%99s", str);
    } while (strlen(str) < 2);
    int opcode = atoi(str + strlen(str) - 2);
}
```

Yes, it's not perfect because it's break when you enter a string with more than 100 char.
But, you can replace the `scanf` by another function who can take a infinite string len.

Comment: How exactly will it break? It's doing scanf() for digit. Your solution is representing the digit as a string.

Comment: Thank you for ``%99`` tips. And i forget ``str`` is alread a pointer, i'm not a big scanf user.

Comment: What happens if the user enters non-numeric input?

Comment: atoi return ``0``, for prevent this, you can add a condition in the while who verify if string is a number or only check of the 2 last char are a digit.

Comment: There is no function that can take an infinite string length.